# Gem on Ruby 1.8 gives "undefined method `dirs' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm getting an `NoMethodError` error with Rubygems (Ruby 1.8).

These are old Rails 2.3 sites so I'm hoping not to have to upgrade to 1.9.

It happens for all gem commands including `gem -v`.

The error is `rubygems.rb:959:in '_deprecated_source_index': undefined method 'dirs' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)`.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
NOTE: Gem.searcher is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.searcher called from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:34.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_path_searcher.rb:81.
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:959:in `_deprecated_source_index': undefined method `dirs' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:39:in `skip_during'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:958:in `_deprecated_source_index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:63:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:63:in `source_index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_path_searcher.rb:81:in `init_gemspecs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_path_searcher.rb:13:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:951:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:951:in `_deprecated_searcher'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:63:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:63:in `searcher'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:34:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/config_file.rb:50
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:8
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/gem:9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade your rubygems. You will have to install it directly from source since your gem command is not working.

I use Ruby 1.8.7 myself and the rubygems version that seems to be doing OK so far is 1.6.0.

http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126